# How to shift DatetimeIndex by x months with relativedelta?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DatetimeIndex in my pandas dataframe in quarterly frequency, formatted to the beginning of quarters (so 1 jan, 1 Apr and so on). I want to reformat it to the end of quarters, (31 Mar, 30 Jun etc).

I figure the easiest method would be to shift the entire index by 3 months and subtract 1 day. The subtraction part is OK, e.g. I can do this to shift the entire index back a day

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import * 
df.index - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

The problem is how to shift ahead 3 months. `timedelta` works in days and weeks, so is not appropriate. I read that `relativedelta` does just this, but it only works for datetime object, not datetimeindex. For instance, the following works

```
df.index[0] + relativedelta(months=+3)
```

but not

```
df.index + relativedelta(months=+3)
```

I guess I can loop over each element of df.index but surely there is an elegant solution that eludes me?

Comment: `df.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)` ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!